# iOS UrlSession.shared.dataTask removes utf-8 "+" character and replaces it with " "

Tags: ios, utf-8, postman, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm creating a login call to an API using x-www-form-endoded data.  I created a POST in Postman and received a 200 response.  I used Postman's export function to generate the OKHTTP code for Android and NSURL code for iOS.  The Android code works fine, but the iOS code receives a 401 response.  I used Charles web debugging proxy to look at what was actually being sent for the payload.  For android the username is correctly represented as "username=james+jypsee@jypsee.com" but in iOS it comes out as "username=james jypsee@jypsee.com". My iOS code is below:

```
let headers = [
  "accept": "application/json",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

let postData = NSMutableData(data: "username=james+jypsee@jypsee.com".data(using: .utf8)!)
postData.append("&password=redacted".data(using: .utf8)!)
postData.append("&grant_type=password".data(using: .utf8)!)
postData.append("&client_id=redacted".data(using: .utf8)!)
postData.append("&client_secret=redacted".data(using: .utf8)!)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://redacted.com/api/oauth2/token/")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData as Data
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })
```

When I stepped through the iOS code both the NSMutableData and Data objects correctly displayed the username as "username=james+jypsee@jypsee.com", just leaving the URLSession.shared as the potential cause of error.  But I can't step into URLSession.shared.dataTask() because its a private method. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some issue with encoding of "+" characters. You can try this instead:

```
let postData = NSMutableData(data: "username=james%2Bjypsee@jypsee.com".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor: I guess space has issues as well. As a matter of fact if your server accepts JSON type, its better to use NSJSONSerialization to create data object from a json and pass that to the server instead of using utf8 on strings.

Comment: The real problem is that you forgot to set the Content-Type header.  The handling of body data is undefined without that.  Your server is probably doing the decoding for you when provided with whatever iOS's default content type is.